# How can I convert httpd.conf markup to .htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf

I'm installing [doxWiki](http://doxwiki.sourceforge.net/), and the webserver installation instructions assume root access to `httpd.conf` -- my provider, [1and1, only allows access to .htaccess](http://faq.1and1.com/miscellaneous/9.html)

Below is the doxWiki `httpd.conf` sample

```
ServerAdmin YourName@YourMail.com

DocumentRoot "/home/doxWiki/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/doxWiki/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /images "/home/doxWiki/images"
    ScriptAlias // "/home/doxWiki/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/home/doxWiki">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/doxWiki/images">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What of the above can be converted to `.htaccess`, and what cannot?

ServerAdmin := not
Alias := rewrite rules
ScriptAlias := not even sure what this is
Directory sections := convertable?

I couldn't find any one source online, or in existing questions, that cover all the issues above. I edit rewrite rules so infrequently that I never remember the details from time to time....

I originally [asked this at StackOverflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204330/how-can-i-convert-httpd-conf-markup-to-htaccess-rules) but thought it might be more appropriate, here.

Comment: I think this more appropriate in ServerFault.com

Comment: What is the dividing line between a server admin and a webmaster? As a webmaster, I have to deal with the .htaccess files, but not server maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

It will mostly depend on which values your host allows to be edited. In theory, *everything* can be put in an `.htaccess` file if they set `AllowOverride All` at the server level.

Have you tried using all your code in an htaccess to test? (You can try it in a subfolder if the site is already live.) If it doesn't work, and you can't find out which values are causing problems, you should ask your host to tell you what you can and can't override.